# How to manage app configuration for android on VMWare Airwatch?

Tags: android, google-workspace, airwatch, emm

I want to managed app configuration for an android application on VMWare Airwatch. I registered with Google Play account for Android EMM Registration before installing .apk. Then I uploaded the .apk internally from Apps&Books > Applications > Native. I am adding assignment to the application I uploaded. When adding an assignment, my android devices appear in the list. But the application does not deploy on my devices.

I can't see my installed app on apps section of hub in phone. But I only encounter this problem when I open the managed access feature. If I do not activate the managed access feature while assigning, the application appears on the hub. Should I do it with EMM Registration G-Suite? Or what could be the reason for this?